# Standard error for lme4 random effect predictions in lme4

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

I have an experiment with plants having different growth habits (`growth_type`), genotypes nested within growth types (`ge`), and blocks also nested within growth types (`block`). The objective is to test the influence of growth type and genotypes of plant performance. Here is a sample data and reproducible example.

```
data1 <- read.csv(text = "
growth_type,ge,block,performance
dwarf,A,1,128.32
dwarf,A,2,97.01
dwarf,A,3,91.05
dwarf,B,1,108.51
dwarf,B,2,121.11
dwarf,B,3,84.15
dwarf,C,1,132.55
dwarf,C,2,129.45
dwarf,C,3,122.33
tall,D,1,79.68
tall,D,2,122.5
tall,D,3,143.42
tall,E,1,149.29
tall,E,2,162.13
tall,E,3,135.42
tall,F,1,90.45
tall,F,2,127.4
tall,F,3,78.99")
```

These are the libraries I used:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lme4)
library(lsmeans)
```

The first step was fitting a model:

```
model.fit <- 
  lmer(performance ~ growth_type + (1 | block:growth_type) + (1 | ge:growth_type),         
       data = data1)
```

From this model, I can extract the fixed effect of growth type using `lsmeans`:

```
fixed.effect.estimates <- lsmeans::lsmeans(model.fit, "growth_type")
```

and this is the output:

[image]

What I need to obtain is the same output for the random effect. I am able to get the prediction interval, but I cannot get the standard error. This is what I tried:

```
# RANDOM EFFECT ESTIMATES
data1$pred.performance <- 
  predict(model.fit, 
          newdata = data1,
          re.form= ~(1 | ge:growth_type)) 

pred.ge <- data1 %>%
  distinct(ge, growth_type, pred.performance)
```

And this is what I've obtained. So far so good.

[image]

Then I used the `bootMer` function to build the prediction interval using bootstrapping.

```
mySumm <- function(.) {
  predict(., newdata=pred.ge, re.form= ~(1 | ge:growth_type))
}

####Collapse bootstrap into median, 95% PI
sumBoot <- function(merBoot) {
  return(
    data.frame(fit = apply(merBoot$t, 2, function(x) as.numeric(quantile(x, probs=.5, na.rm=TRUE))),
               lwr = apply(merBoot$t, 2, function(x) as.numeric(quantile(x, probs=.025, na.rm=TRUE))),
               upr = apply(merBoot$t, 2, function(x) as.numeric(quantile(x, probs=.975, na.rm=TRUE)))
        )
  )
}

##lme4::bootMer() method 1
PI.boot1.time <- system.time(
  boot1 <- lme4::bootMer(model.fit, mySumm, nsim=250, use.u=TRUE, type="parametric")
)

PI.boot1 <- sumBoot(boot1)

cbind(pred.ge, PI.boot1)
```

This is what I obtained:

[image]

In summary, my questions are:

1. how can I get the standard errors as I did for the fixed effect components?
2. why random effect estimates from `lme4::predict` are different from `lme4::bootMer`?

Sorry for a long explanation.

Comment: Fixed effects are location estimates. Random effects are variances/standard deviations. Do you really want a standard error of a variance estimate? Why?

Comment: @Roland,  What I need is a measure of uncertainty for the prediction of the random effects (i.e. blups for each individual he). As I indicated in the table above, I was able to build prediction CI but I'd like to get the standard error.

Comment: And I don't understand why you need a standard error. The CI would appear much more useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Roland. I see your point and I might be probably asking the wrong question base on lack of deep knowledge of mixed models. My intention was trying to get the same output as with the fixed effect estimates. Buy I agree CI are more useful. Any hint on why the estimates with ```lme4::predict``` are different from ```lme4:bootMer```? I understand they are calculated differently but wanted to check if its expected for them to differ.